# How can I populate data (from CSV file) into sqlite database using custom management command in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to read csv file and populate its data into sqlite database.However, when I checked whether the data was inserted, it returns empty "QuerySet []".

here is my code:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
import csv
from students.models import Student

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'import data'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
       file = "../students/data.csv"
       with open(file,newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
           reader = csv.reader(f)
           for w in reader:
               created = Student.objects.update_or_create(student_id = int(w[0]), gender = w[1], dob=w[2])
               created.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

- `update_or_create` will return `student: Student, created: boolean` instead of `created: boolean`.
- You should have the same amount of indents for all lines.
- `created.save()` is not necessary. `update_or_create()` will automatically save your object.

If it still doesn't work. Debug the outcome of `w`.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import csv

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from students.models import Student


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'import data'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        pass
        # this is optional so that your management command can just accept the
        # path of the csv instead of a hardcoded path
        # parser.add_argument(
        #     'csv_file',
        #     help='path to csv file',
        #     type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # (OPTIONAL) please read the comment above
        # csv_file = options.get('csv_file', '')
        csv_file = '../students/data.csv'

        if not os.path.isfile(csv_file):
            print('file not found!')
            return

        with open(csv_file, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            for row in reader:
                # update_or_create will return a tuple
                # first item is the student instance
                # the second identifies if the student is newly created or
                # not(updated)
                student, created = Student.objects.update_or_create(
                    student_id=int(row['student_id']), gender=row['gender'],
                    dob=row['dob'])
```

Things to take note:

- `update_or_create` returns a tuple (x, y) where x is the model instance and y is the boolean if the transaction created a new Student or not.
- the path of the csv is relative to where you are calling the `manage.py` (not so sure)

Example directory

```
└── app
    ├── manage.py
    ├── student.csv

# you can then have
csv_file = 'student.csv'

# and this is what your code above is expecting

└── app
    ├── manage.py
└── student
    ├── student.csv
```

Comment: How about if I want to pass two paths (one for csv file as you have shown above) and the second one is just folder location?

Comment: if you want to add additional args just add an `add_argument` to your parsers, (inside the `add_arguments` function). but not so sure why you need to separately input the csv file and the directory.